# Is Eliezer's daughter anybody?

Tags: eliezer

[Rashi to Breishit 24:39](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.24.39?lang=he&with=Rashi&lang2=he) mentions Eliezer's daughter. Oftentimes unnamed characters have traditions linking them to named characters. Is Eliezer's daughter anybody? (and don't say "oh, she was the daughter of Eliezer")

Comment: Disclaimer. I forgot Eliezer's daughter isn't actually in the Torah. Still. Is she anyone?

Comment: my own [thought](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vRATp_38Y9k6OiB5oieOlV_HvQpMJwDiONvOXzFefHNWWC7U0lS02p-iCjpElCv8lmEu7qbOuv2nQLa/pub) is that her name is listed in the pasuk, "Bakol".

Comment: A quick search indicated that the answer is: no; she was not anybody.

Comment: The Conservation of Biblical Personalities http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26136/759

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/109891/170

Comment: @DoubleAA https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33532/170