# Eliezer's daughter and descendants

Tags: midrash, parashat-chaye-sara, eliezer

Medrash Rabah Parshas Chayai Sara 59:9 says that Eliezer had a daughter and was hoping that she would marry Yitzchak. Avraham told him you are cursed (come from a cursed family) and my son is blessed. A cursed person does not connect to a blessed one.

Are there any sources that discuss who Eliezer's daughter married in the end and who her descendants are?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77912/is-eliezers-daughter-anybody

Comment: @msh210 This is a dupe and should be merged. But this is worded better.